# How to get the current cursor type in Java?

Tags: java, windows, winapi, cursor

I want to test wether the mouse hovers currently over text or a button etc.
I have been searching for about an hour or so and I couldn't find anything that worked.

And if that doesn't work with Java alone, could you somehow access the Win32 library to get the cursor type?

regards, TPRammus

EDIT: I generally want the cursor type, even if my application is not focused.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to get the cursor type if the user is not focused on the java application.

Comment: @JamalH Hmm is that any different from other programming languages such as C++? Could you get the cursor type in C++?

Comment: I don't think any operating system would allow it on any programming language. Think about it, it would be a security concern if you embedded code into your app that could see what people are doing in other applications. Hackers could use that to steal information

Comment: @JamalH Yeah I get what you mean but the programming language wouldn't really need to access any other application at all. Only the current cursor...

Comment: @JamalH This is exactly what VNC applications and keyloggers do. They track the keys you press, the cursor and the screen. So yes, low-level apps are capable of doing this, but java can't.

Comment: @BackSlash Yes but on those you have to install them and "allow them to make changes to your computer"

Comment: @JamalH It really depends on the security settings of the OS. i.e. I wrote a simple keylogger with C# which didn't ask for permissions at all, it just started logging. But that's not the point, the point is that you can do it with native low level code.

Comment: @BackSlash So what do you mean with low-level apps? Could you give me a push in the right direction?
If I cant do it in Java I'll have to switch anyways...

Comment: @TPRammus You probably want to have a look at Win32 Mouse Hooks

Comment: One wonders why you are interested in this information. My guess is that your imagined solution to the problem is not the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

These two functions from awt package are for the type and location of the cursor may be helpful:

java.awt.Cursor.getType()

Or

java.awt.MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()

Comment: I think he wants it for external applications, not his own

Comment: Yes I generally want the cursor type, even if my application is not focused.

Comment: @Jamal H Maybe, it wasn't clear for me, if he wants it for an external app then this answer isn't applicable